# Create a continous variable force on object

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid, electromagnetic

I have a component that I need to press to another component with ideally max 200 Newton of force. I want to be able to to control this force. E.g I should be able to have half the force or 1/10 the force.

I only need a very small amount of travel. 1mm would already be enough. My idea is to use a linear solenoid like this [one](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/linear-solenoids/1736445/). And the control the current to control the force the solenoid provides. Another solution I thought about is to use a bar a holding magnet like this
[one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32827652840.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.292152afENJunu&algo_pvid=39c59095-86b5-4905-8352-b84a0afd5843&algo_expid=39c59095-86b5-4905-8352-b84a0afd5843-3&btsid=33933dcf-cce6-4179-8235-a92a171913ae&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_53) and use a permanent magnet to on the other side to create repulsion between the holding magnet and the holding magnet if I power the holding magnet. However the force a bit too low.

I have never used solenoids before and I wonder if there is some alternative that might work better for my case. I don't really have much room so large solutions

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: An very important factor to understand is how will you monitor the force being applied. Your variable range implies some type of sensor feedback and yet you have not mentioned anything about that.

Comment: @MichaelKaras My idea was to measure it once using force sensor separate from the setup then store that in a lookup table on a microcontroller.

Comment: OK then so it sounds like you intend to operate open loop with fixed data points. Whatever solution you end up with to apply the force make sure other factors do not put you outside desired tolerance range. Those factors can include temperature and voltage variations, mechanical mechanism repeat ability, and device under test variations.

Comment: 200N or 20kg requires very high Amp-turns. This is the lowest I found https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-24V-0-1A-20kg-Force-Sucked-Type-Round-Solenoid-Electromagnet/273761764393?hash=item3fbd790429:g:D2AAAOSwHWddbzur

Comment: Please explain EXACTLY how much room you do have. This makes a vast difference to what will work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with solenoids is that the force is strongly dependent on plunger position.

You might get away with it given the small range of motion, but a better option is generally a 'voice coil' actuator (I use one for cutting depth control in a record lathe, significantly less annoying then a solenoid). 
200N is quite a large load, you might benefit from some mechanical advantage (A lever)?